# Issue regarding Pie Chart in CRM 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I have a Pie chart which is based on out-of-box 'Activity' entity. The issue is regarding the following line:-

```
<attribute groupby="true" alias="groupby_column" name="scheduledend" dategrouping="week" />
```

Since, I am doing grouping on the 'Weekly' basis, due to which 'Horizontal (category) axis labels' are coming as Week 51 of 2011, Week 52 of 2011, etc. What I want is to modify this axis labels as Week 1, Week 2...? But, I am unable to find the solution for it. Any idea, any workaround is highly appreciated.

Btw, following is the XML which I am using :-

```
<visualization>
  <visualizationid>{4930EBE4-3317-E111-B519-005056B20058}</visualizationid>
  <name>My Team's Aging Activities</name>
  <primaryentitytypecode>activitypointer</primaryentitytypecode>
  <datadescription>
    <datadefinition>
      <fetchcollection>
        <fetch mapping="logical" aggregate="true">
          <entity name="activitypointer">
            <attribute alias="aggregate_column" name="activityid" aggregate="count" />
            <attribute groupby="true" alias="groupby_column" name="scheduledend" dategrouping="week" />
            <filter type="and">
              <condition attribute="scheduledend" operator="next-x-weeks" value="4" />
              <condition attribute="scheduledend" operator="not-null" />
            </filter>
          </entity>
        </fetch>
      </fetchcollection>
      <categorycollection>
        <category>
          <measurecollection>
            <measure alias="aggregate_column" />
          </measurecollection>
        </category>
      </categorycollection>
    </datadefinition>
  </datadescription>
  <presentationdescription>
    <Chart Palette="None" PaletteCustomColors="97,142,206; 209,98,96; 168,203,104; 142,116,178; 93,186,215; 255,155,83; 148,172,215; 217,148,147; 189,213,151; 173,158,196; 145,201,221; 255,180,138">
      <Series>
        <Series ShadowOffset="0" IsValueShownAsLabel="true" Font="{0}, 9.5px" LabelForeColor="59, 59, 59" CustomProperties="PieLabelStyle=Inside, PieDrawingStyle=Default" ChartType="pie">
          <SmartLabelStyle Enabled="True" />
        </Series>
      </Series>
      <ChartAreas>
        <ChartArea>
          <Area3DStyle Enable3D="true" />
        </ChartArea>
      </ChartAreas>
      <Legends>
        <Legend Alignment="Center" LegendStyle="Table" Docking="right" IsEquallySpacedItems="True" Font="{0}, 11px" ShadowColor="0, 0, 0, 0" ForeColor="59, 59, 59" />
      </Legends>
      <Titles>
        <Title Alignment="TopLeft" DockingOffset="-3" Font="{0}, 13px" ForeColor="0, 0, 0"></Title>
      </Titles>
    </Chart>
  </presentationdescription>
  <isdefault>false</isdefault>
</visualization>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The field you are referring to is called LegendText, and according to CRM Chart Guy the legend text on a pie chart cannot be changed (See "Stuff we unfortunately cannot do.." at the end of the article).

http://crmchartguy.wordpress.com/2014/03/13/all-things-pie-chart-in-dynamics-crm/